# Drag a sprite by its 2D Polygon Collider component

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, drag-and-drop, position

I've got a draggable class that works great for dragging entire sprites and I'm trying to modify it to register dragging only within the defined 2D polygon collider component of the sprite object. I'm having a really hard time getting the drag to only register when I click within the boundaries of the polygon collider. Right now it's still dragging wherever I click-drag on the sprite including outside the boundaries of my polygon collider. I could really use some guidance on this. I've also attached an image to illustrate what I'm trying to achieve. Thanks!

[image]

```
PolygonCollider2D collider;

    void Start ()
    {
        collider = transform.GetComponent<PolygonCollider2D>();
    }

    public void OnDrag (PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Vector3 mousePosition = new Vector3(eventData.position.x, eventData.position.y, 0);
        collider.transform.position = mousePosition;                                       

    if(transform.parent.gameObject == partsPanel)
            transform.SetParent(dragLayer.transform);                                      

        if(transform.parent.gameObject == buildBoard)
            transform.SetParent(dragLayer.transform);
    }
```

Comment: Not so clear, do you have any snapshots?

Comment: Hi @David, I've added a screenshot to illustrate.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I know this is very old thread, but I had similar problem and I found a solution so I will post it here :)

Just create a class with this code and put it on your object

```
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(RectTransform), typeof(Collider2D))]
public class Collider2DRaycastFilter : MonoBehaviour, ICanvasRaycastFilter
{
Collider2D myCollider;
RectTransform rectTransform;

void Awake()
{
    myCollider = GetComponent<Collider2D>();
    rectTransform = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
}

public bool IsRaycastLocationValid(Vector2 screenPos, Camera eventCamera)
{
    var worldPoint = Vector3.zero;
    var isInside = RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToWorldPointInRectangle(
        rectTransform,
        screenPos,
        eventCamera,
        out worldPoint
    );
    if (isInside)
        isInside = myCollider.OverlapPoint(worldPoint);
    return isInside;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, The polygon collider we added to the sprite is editable. Goto inspector, collider component and there is a button which allow editing collider area. Adjust the points of this collider to cover just the desired area. This way only the desired area will receive touch events.

Comment: I know how to edit the collider in the editor, what i need help with is modifying my script to use that collider as the draggable area

Comment: Ok if you have edited the collider component then give this a try: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDrag.html

Comment: Make sure this  edited polygon collider is the only collider component attached to this game object.